# How do i handle state management while working with next js

Tags: redux, next.js, state-management

Í am A newbie working with the MERN stacks, I just managed to build an ecommerce website from scratch,but then I hear nextjs is good for server side rendering which make our web app load faster and also seo friendly, I looked into the documentàtion, but I am yet to understand how I mange state in next js...càn I use redux,and how?
Thanks

Comment: Just like you do it in the react, you can do it in the next.js as well. If you want to to utilize the redux, you can do so just like you do in react-redux app

Comment: Thanks alot, I will put that into practice

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to integrate redux into Next.js

These examples come from the official Next.js repo

[with redux](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux)

[with redux-toolkit](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-toolkit)

[with redux-thunk](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-thunk)

if you want to manage state with redux on server-side, you can follow this example [with next-redux-wrappper](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper)